# Error: ext4magic Error 13 while opening filesystem

Tags: ext4, data-recovery, ext4magic

I'm trying to recover an accidentally removed directory (`/home/garid/.gnupg`) with `ext4magic`. However, It outputs following error:

```bash
$ ext4magic /dev/nvme0n1p3  -f /home/garid/.gnupg/  -a $(date -d -5days +%s)
/dev/nvme0n1p3 Error 13 while opening filesystem
ext4magic : EXIT_SUCCESS
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. What is `Error 13`? And How can I make it work?

---

My distro is Archlinux. My Partition table:

```
nvme0n1     259:0    0 476.9G  0 disk
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0     1G  0 part /efi
├─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0    32G  0 part [SWAP]
└─nvme0n1p3 259:3    0 443.9G  0 part /
```

---

As suggested in below, running as root outputs below:

```
$ sudo ext4magic /dev/nvme0n1p3  -f /home/garid/.gnupg/  -a $(date -d -5days +%s)
[sudo] password for garid:
Filesystem in use: /dev/nvme0n1p3

Using  internal Journal at Inode 8
Activ Time after  : Sun Feb 26 20:15:57 2023
Activ Time before : Fri Mar  3 20:15:58 2023
zsh: segmentation fault  sudo ext4magic /dev/nvme0n1p3 -f /home/garid/.gnupg/ -a $(date -d -5days +%s)
```

Answer (score 0):

Error 13 is “permission denied”. You need to run `ext4magic` as root:

```
sudo ext4magic /dev/nvme0n1p3  -f /home/garid/.gnupg/  -a $(date -d -5days +%s)
```

Comment: I just ran it with root, got error, and updated question above.